# I need assistance preventing both a checked and unchecked checkbox from posting at the same time

Tags: php, post, checkbox, hidden

I have created a table of checkboxes.  The rows are divided up by category, and either a checked or unchecked checkbox gets displayed under a department column.  I have a lot of code so I will break down what I am supplying.  I am creating an array via each column (odd method, yes).  I have noticed that if all check boxes are deselected, it will return the hidden value of 0 each time it loops. Thats great, thats what I wanted.  However, if the box is selected, it returns both the value of 0 and the value of 3.  For instance:

Test = Array()

Test[0] => 0
Test[1] => 3

How can I prevent it from posting the hidden value?

```
$row_two = mysql_query("SELECT dept_id FROM categories WHERE cat_name = '{$cats['cat_name']}' and bus_id = '{$busUnits['bus_id']}'");
            while (($test_two=mysql_fetch_assoc($row_two)))
            {
                $AnotherTest =  implode(',', $test_two);
                $WhatTest = explode(",", $AnotherTest);
                if(in_array("3",$WhatTest, TRUE))
                {
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="Cat_CBC_Test_One[]" value="0">';
                    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="Cat_CBC_Test_One[]" value="3" checked></td>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="Cat_CBC_Test_One[]" value="0">';
                    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="Cat_CBC_Test_One[]" value="3"></td>';
                }
```

Comment: The issue I was having dealt with checked checkboxes.  In my Ins_Cat.php file I had print_R($errAccSup) where $errAccSup = $_POST["Cat_CBC_Test_One"].

Say I had 7 categories. and the column looked like this
X
X
X
_
_
_
X

There would be 4 checked checkboxes, and three unchecked.  I would get the following...

0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3

Answer (score 0):

To detect unchecked Checkboxes i would add a hidden field with a different name, like `_Cat_CBC_Test_One`. That way you dont have the issue with the hidden field interfering.

Then, on the server, you scan through for parameters that start with `_` and add the missing "false" Parameters for further processing.